# How can i get setState to work in an event handler in a functional React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am refactoring a MERN app to use hooks and context, so I'm changing class components to functions.  One component has a form that changes state based on the keystrokes in an input field, like:

```
    class CreateAccountComp extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.state = {
        firstName: null,
        lastName: null,
        email: null,
        password: null,
        githubID: null,
    };
  }

  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.handleInputChange();
    API.getsync(this.state.githubID, this.state.firstName, this.state.lastName, this.state.email);
    ...
    })
  };

  handleChange = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    ...
    this.setState({ [name]: value }, () => null);
  };
  ....
```

This works after the callback was added to the 'this.setState' statement.

The new component looks like this:

```
const CreateAccountComp = (props) => {

  const [state, setState] = useState({
    firstName: null,
    lastName: null,
    email: null,
    password: null,
    githubID: null,
  });

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("HMMMM leaving CreateAccountcomp");
    props.handleInputChange();
    API.getsync(state.githubID, state.firstName, state.lastName, state.email);
    ...
  };

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    ...
    setState({ [name]: value });
  };
```

Now, I can't use a callback to deal with the asynchronous `setState` statement, and the state properties being passed to the `API.getsync()` function are undefined.

My research comes up with examples of using async/await or useEffect, but they all deal with single calls to an external api.  Here, I'm running `handleChange` to render the keystrokes into the input fields in a form, then running `handleSubmit` via `onSubmit` to execute a function to update the database based on the state values.  Is there a way to update state properly in this function component?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `useEffect` hook and add `state` as a dependency to the `useEffect` hook so that it runs every time the `state` object changes

```
useEffect(() => {
    // code to run every time `state` object changes
    API.getsync(state.githubID, state.firstName, state.lastName, state.email);
}, [state]);
```

You are also not updating the state correctly. Unlike `this.setState`, which merges the previous state with the new one, function returned by `useState` hook will overwrite the previous state with the new state.

To avoid overwriting the state, make sure you merge the previous state with the new one manually

```
const handleChange = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { name, value } = e.target;

    setState({ ...state, [name]: value });
};
```

Keep in mind that `useEffect` hook will also run when the component renders for the first time. After that, it will run only when the `state` object is changed.

### Edit:

If you don' want to make the HTTP request when `useEffect` runs on initial render of the component, add an `if` statement inside the `useEffect` hook's callback that will make sure that HTTP request is only made once you have required data in the `state` object to make the HTTP request

```
useEffect(() => {

    if (state.githubID) {
        API.getsync(state.githubID, state.firstName, state.lastName, state.email);
    }

}, [state]);
```

Comment: I tried this and the problem is that 'getsync' runs on load, which loads bad data into my database and skips the form to provide the github user name.  Apparently, when the github api is hit with a user name that is undefined, it returns some random information.

I solved this by deleting the code from inside useEffect.  Crude, but it works.

Comment: You can prevent useEffect from making a HTTP request when component renders for the first time by adding an if statement that checks whether you have required data in the state to make the request. See the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yousaf got me on the right track, however, the code needed to be revised to work.  This issue was that by executing 'API.getsync(state.githubID, state.firstName, state.lastName, state.email);' on initial load, the database was receiving data, which told the app that user information from github was there and the form to input the user name was never rendered.  Apparently, the github api will respond with valid, but incorrect, information if the user name is undefined.  The api is hit via:

```
axios
.get(
  "https://api.github.com/users/" + developerLoginName + "/repos?type=all"
```

This resulted in information on 4 repositories for user 'null' being added to the database!

This was resolved by removing the line calling the getsync function from useEffect.

However, I found that useEffect wasn't needed at all.  Just adding the spread operator to the 'setState' made it work.